# How to disable Buttons inside a Tableview added programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have added some UIButtons to a table view. The tableview is present inside a View and has other Buttons. On a event, I am trying to disable all the butons in the View including the ones addded programmatically in the tableview. I am able to disable other Buttons but I am unable to disable the Buttons that I add to the table view.

The Structure is like this:

```
UITabbarController
|
|---> ViewController01
|*************************|---> View
|************************************|---> tableview
|
|---> ViewController02
**************************|---> View
**************************************|---> tableview
```

The Table View occupying the views partially, I have other UIButtons as part of the view other than tableView. Initially I did not had any tableviews inside my views and I had only UIButtons in the view.

I was disabling all the UIButtons in UITabBarController using the following code:

```
-(void) enableAllButtonsInTabBar:(BOOL)enable {
NSMutableArray* viewsArray01 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.ViewController01.view.subviews];
NSMutableArray* viewsArray02 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.ViewController02.view.subviews];

[viewsArray01 removeObject:self.ViewControlloer01.progressView];
[viewsArray02 removeObject:self.ViewController02.progressView];

for (UIButton* button in viewsArray01) {
    [button setEnabled:enable];
}
for (UIButton* button in viewsArray02) {
    [button setEnabled:enable];
}
}
```

Now I would want to achieve the same thing but I am unable to access the UIButtons that I add programmatically in th ViewController01 and ViewController02 to the table views.

Although I have tried to hide it using:

```
for (UITableView *view in viewsArray02) {
[view setHidden:YES];
}
```

But this is not what I want.

Comment: show your event code and whats your tableview button name

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried putting the logic to disable the buttons in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method by cycling through the UIButtons (views) and disabling each one?

Comment: @anbu: It's doesn't matter what the button name is, and the event is nothing but on clicking on one of the buttons I am running some background processes and would wait for them to finish. In the mean time before the background processes complete , I want to disable all the buttons in the view.

Comment: @timgcarlson: No I haven't tried that. I would certainly try to see if it works. My tableview is a part of one of the view controllers of a tab bar view controller. And I am trying to to disable the buttons in the tab bar view controller

Comment: If you're trying to disable the buttons in the tab bar controller, that is not in your tableview. In fact, your table view knows nothing about your tab bar controller. Look for your view controller that manages the UITabBar and access the buttons from there.

Comment: Are the buttons in table view cells?

Comment: @mike: Yes the UIButtons are in table view cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Tableview cells get released when they are no longer visible on the screen. So when I was trying to access the UIButtons in my other view controller (tabbar view controller), the buttons were no longer accessible. So Ended up doing some like this.

- Have my own NSMutableArray of buttons and access them in other view controllers  whenever I want them to.

  ```
  @interface debugButton : NSObject
  @property NSString * buttonTitle;
  @property BOOL isEnabled;

  @end

  @implementation debugButton
  @end

  @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttonsArray;

  self.buttonsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  debugButton *button;
  button = [[debugButton alloc] initWithTitle:@"item1" enable:YES];
  button.buttonTitle = @"item2”;
  [self.buttonsArray addObject:button];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Do try this .

You should be setting up your button as a IBOutlet.
In .h :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

In .m :

@synthesize myButton;

```
[myButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: You don't need the `@synthesize` anymore. @Irfanlone I will admit I found it hard to follow you question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the buttons are in UITableViewCells, the subviews of the table view cells aren't included in the table view's subviews array.

I just created a simple UITableView that has a few cells with some buttons inside. Printing out `self.view.subviews` in the debugger, I get the following:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7b920e50>(
<UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7b933960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b933f20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b933c60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd57cf0; frame = (16 307.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4b390>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd4a070; frame = (16 351.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4d410>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ea20; frame = (16 395.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4d7b0>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5c500; frame = (16 439.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4e6e0>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd529b0; frame = (16 483.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5b650>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd4d350; frame = (16 527.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d9c0>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ddd0; frame = (16 571.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5e7c0>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5de90; frame = (16 615.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5bd40>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd54ac0; frame = (16 659.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4bf60>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd56c40; frame = (16 703.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d110>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5c6c0; frame = (16 747.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5c740>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ecc0; frame = (16 791.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5eba0>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd56170; frame = (16 835.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5ec00>>,
<_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd561f0; frame = (16 879.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd56270>>,
<UIImageView: 0x7bd52ea0; frame = (317.5 561; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd52f20>>,
<UIImageView: 0x7bd52620; frame = (313 565.5; 7 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd52940>>
)
```

As you can see none of the cells or contents of them are a part of the 'subviews' of the tableview.

Printing out `[self.view recursiveDescription]` shows this:

```
<UITableView: 0x7daea400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b9331f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b932b80>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 264}>
   | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x7b933960; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b933f20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b933c60>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd5df40; frame = (0 220; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5dda0>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd5e110; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd5e320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5e180>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd5e370; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5e470>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5e520; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5e5a0>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd5d140; frame = (0 176; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4d320>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd5d310; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd5d520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d380>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd5d570; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d670>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5d720; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d7a0>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd5b420; frame = (0 132; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd52980>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd56300; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd57ac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd56370>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd55a20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd57b00>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd57990; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd57a10>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd4b980; frame = (0 88; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4e540>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd4bb10; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd56610>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4fec0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd48140; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd253b0>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd57bf0; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd56f10>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd5c770; frame = (0 44; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5c4d0>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd5cac0; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd5cdd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5cb30>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd5ce20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5cf20>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5d050; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd49da0>>
   |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x7bd55890; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd55bc0>>
   |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x7bd56100; frame = (0 0; 320 43.5); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bd56a30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd562d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bd56aa0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd56ce0>>
   |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd578f0; frame = (16 43.5; 304 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd57a90>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd57cf0; frame = (16 307.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4b390>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd4a070; frame = (16 351.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4d410>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ea20; frame = (16 395.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4d7b0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5c500; frame = (16 439.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4e6e0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd529b0; frame = (16 483.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5b650>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd4d350; frame = (16 527.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d9c0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ddd0; frame = (16 571.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5e7c0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5de90; frame = (16 615.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5bd40>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd54ac0; frame = (16 659.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd4bf60>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd56c40; frame = (16 703.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5d110>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5c6c0; frame = (16 747.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5c740>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd5ecc0; frame = (16 791.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5eba0>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd56170; frame = (16 835.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd5ec00>>
   | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x7bd561f0; frame = (16 879.5; 304 0.5); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd56270>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7bd52ea0; frame = (317.5 561; 2.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd52f20>>
   | <UIImageView: 0x7bd52620; frame = (313 565.5; 7 2.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bd52940>>
```

The easiest thing to do would be something like the creating a BOOL property/instance variable that is set to YES/NO depending on if you want the buttons enabled or disabled, and in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method when you create/customize your cells, you can simply set the button enabled state to this variable.

Whenever you want your state to change, update that variable and call `reloadData` and your cells should update accordingly.